# How to use swapExactETHForTokens methods with ethers.js properly?

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, ethers.js

I want to use swapExactETHForTokens() method inside node.js app with ethers.js library, but transaction always fails because of not including variable `msg.value` (from docs: 'The amount of ETH to send.' It's present in docs but I don't know how can I incude it inside code) But in method declaration this var is not present, only var `amountOutMin`. So how is it possible to use this var and make the swap success?
My code:

```
const WBNBHERORouterContract = new ethers.Contract(
    router,
    [
        `function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) internal view returns (uint[] memory amounts)`,
        `function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts)`
    ],
    signer
);
const tx = await WBNBHERORouterContract.swapExactETHForTokens(
            wbnbAmount,
            minAmountToBuy,
            [WBNB, HERO],
            wallet.address,
            Date.now() + 1000 * 60,
            {gasLimit: 251234}
        )

receipt = await tx.wait();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be necessary to specify the address that the WBNB sends and how much it sends

```
  const tx = await WBNBHERORouterContract.swapExactETHForTokens(
            wbnbAmount,
            minAmountToBuy,
            [WBNB, HERO],
            wallet.address,
            Date.now() + 1000 * 60,
            {from : ..... , value: ... , gasLimit: 251234}
        ) 
    
receipt = await tx.wait();
```